# AWS DataPipeline: SellCommandPrecondition does not fail

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-data-pipeline

Using ShellCommandPrecondition for a SQLActivity with Datapipeline. In the python script, if I use sys.exit(0) (success signal) then the Precondition returns successfully and pipeline continues to execute. But if I use sys.exit(1) (error signal) then the Precondition does not return and stays in Running state indefinitely.

But with SellCommandActivity, if I use sys.exit(1) then it fails gracefully and following activities fail.

Why ShellCommandPrecondition does not exhibit same behavior as SellCommandActivity or is this is a bug in AWS Datapipeline and needs to rectified?

Answer (score 0):

The three [properties](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-object-shellcommandprecondition.html) to look at are:

- `maximumRetries`
- `retryDelay`
- `preconditionTimeout`

If your script fails (with a non-zero return code) on the first attempt, the precondition will not immediately fail. Instead it will pause for `retryDelay` and execute again up to `maximumRetries`. The total amount of time the precondition will allow for all attempts is determined by `preconditionTimeout`.